# chrome: Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader

Tags: chrome, alpine-linux, podman, gpu-passthrough

I'm trying to run headless Chrome in a container using Alpine Linux, I'm getting

> Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader

The commands to get this are pretty simple,

```bsh
podman run -ti alpine:3 /bin/sh <<EOF
  apk update;
  apk add chromium chromium-swiftshader;

  chromium-browser                \
    --headless                    \
    --use-gl=swiftshader          \
    --disable-software-rasterizer \
    --disable-dev-shm-usage       \
    --enable-webgl                \
    --no-sandbox;
EOF
```

What I get is a log like this,

```
[1207/044552.896481:WARNING:dns_config_service_linux.cc(470)] Failed to read DnsConfig.
[1207/044552.903662:WARNING:vaapi_wrapper.cc(589)] VAAPI video acceleration not available for swiftshader
[1207/044552.903753:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(441)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader
[1207/044552.942968:WARNING:dns_config_service_linux.cc(470)] Failed to read DnsConfig.
```

How can I run headless chrome? What am I doing wrong? What is "passthrough" and why isn't it supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this does show up as an `ERROR` and is not a warning, this is not a problem for me. My instance of chrome works in webdriver just fine.